# Durable Entity function doesn't trigger or receive data from streaming analytics

Tags: azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics, azure-durable-functions, azure-digital-twins

The durable entity function I've setup as output for a streaming analytics job doesn't trigger or receive any data. I can see incoming input data in the stream analytics job and it outputs to store the data correctly (for a stream analytics job storage output test I also setup). If I test the CalculatePositioni function with postman the function and entity receives the data and updates the state correctly.

I also get a binding error for the function app and I can't see what's missing:

Stream Analytics Job output with my duration funcapp setup:
[image]

I selected keyname default at output creation. I note don't see anywhere or local.settings.json in the function app where I'd need to enter the hashed key.

[image]

My function app.

```
namespace BladeFunctionApps
{

public static class TransformAlgorithm
{
    public static async Task Process_Algorithm([EntityTrigger] IDurableEntityContext context, ILogger log)
    {
        //Set or Get intermediate calculation state values
        Algorithm_SaveStateVariables intermediate_calc_results;
        if (context.HasState)
        {
            intermediate_calc_results = context.GetState<Algorithm_SaveStateVariables>();
            log.LogInformation("Success getting state values: CumItems:" + intermediate_calc_results.AverageMagnetometerX + 
                " Avg:"+ intermediate_calc_results.AverageMagnetometerX);
        }
        else
        {
            log.LogError("Failed to get state values.");
            intermediate_calc_results = new Algorithm_SaveStateVariables();
        }

        //Get values from incoming Json object and perform calculations
        JObject deviceBatchMessage = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(context.GetInput<string>());

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int incomingDataLines = rnd.Next(1, 10);
        intermediate_calc_results.DataItemsNumber=incomingDataLines++;

        bool parsebool=float.TryParse(deviceBatchMessage["body"]["magnetX"].ToString(), out float tempMagnX);
        if(parsebool)
            intermediate_calc_results.AverageMagnetometerX+= tempMagnX;
        else
        {
            log.LogError("Could not parse to float: " + deviceBatchMessage["body"]["magnetX"].ToString());
            intermediate_calc_results.AverageMagnetometerX += 0;
        }

        context.SetState(intermediate_calc_results);
    }

    [FunctionName("CalculatePosition")]
    public static async Task<ActionResult> CalculateTransform(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        [DurableClient] IDurableEntityClient client, ILogger log)
    {
        //read data
        // Extract the body from the request
        log.LogInformation("I'm at the top of CalculatePosition");
        string jsonContent = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonContent))
        {
            log.LogInformation("CalculatePosition: Received Data null or empty.");
            return new StatusCodeResult(204); // 204, ASA connectivity check
        }
        else
            log.LogInformation("CalculatePosition: Received Data:" + jsonContent);

        //send data to algo for processing
        var entityId = new EntityId(nameof(Process_Algorithm), "ProcessTransformAlgorithm");
        await client.SignalEntityAsync(entityId,"FullOperation",jsonContent);

        return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"CalculatePosition: CalculatePosition Success");
    }
}
}
```

[image]

What binding is missing?
[image]

[image]

The input/output setup with Query in the Stream Analytics Job should work, I think so because it's the same setup that I use to output into a blob and works with the blob, not with Azure Steam analytics.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Sergio, can you share any resources/tutorials you might have used in setting up this solution. I have come across this article where it points out the steps needed to [Update stream analytics job with function as an output](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/fcb810f7-f824-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0) Please refer to step 4 of the article and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi @LeelaRajesh_Sayana I've gone through the 37 pages in the link you sent but Ctrl+F on the "Update stream analytics job with function as an output" didn't yield results, can you please provide the direct link to this ? I'm adding herein resources I hope help: MXChip Firmware: https://github.com/azure-rtos/getting-started/tree/master/MXChip/AZ3166 ; Stream analytics to function app https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-with-azure-functions

Comment: Hi Sergio, thank you sharing the additional information. Apologies for the misplaced URL. Here is the link to the correct resource - [Update the Stream Analytics job with the function as output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-with-azure-functions#update-the-stream-analytics-job-with-the-function-as-output). This points to the second URL you have shared but targets the binding section. Please refer to point 4 in the section. Here is another [example](https://jimbobbennett.github.io/AgroHack/Steps/CreateFunction.html)

Comment: Thank you @LeelaRajesh_Sayana , the bindings in this article refers to Redis which does not apply in this simpler scenario more similar to the python example you have kindly posted. I think the existing bindings and shown above are correct further confirmed because stream analytics with the same input/output and query correctly save the data in a blob as output. Also If I test the durable function app in postman it receives the data from IoT hub, but I can't get stream analytics to send it to the function app. I can't figure out what's missing

Comment: Hi Sergio, apologies for the delayed response. The bindings are still valid to your Azure function even if it doesn't write to Redis. The purpose of the query is to push data from Azure stream analytics into the function when the job has started. Are you passing any key to validate the request when testing the Azure function through postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run a query on your Azure stream analytics job to make the data flow into your Azure function. Before you run the query, you would have to set the output alias name when you bind the Azure function as output to the Azure stream analytics job.

Here is where you can provide the alias name
[image]

Once you have the properties defined, you can create a query to push data into the output alias and onto the Azure function. Here is a sample query showing the same.
[image]

The query varies based on the data or fields you have in the stream analytics job. Please refer to this tutorial [Update the Stream Analytics job with the function as output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-with-azure-functions#update-the-stream-analytics-job-with-the-function-as-output) for more detailed information. Here is another [example](https://jimbobbennett.github.io/AgroHack/Steps/CreateFunction.html) that would guide you with the binding and the configuration process.

Here is an HTTPTrigger function I have created to test the data flow between Azure Stream Analytics job and Azure function. The behavior would be the same for durable function as it also uses HTTPTrigger.

```
public static class StreamAnalyticsFunction
{
    [FunctionName("StreamAnalyticsFunction")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string name = req.Query["name"];

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        name = name ?? data?.name;

        string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
            ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
            : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

        return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
    }
}
```

Here is my function integration and data flow

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you @LeeLaRajesh_Sayana , I did and the query captures it all and testing this same setup to capture the logs in a blob works, so don't see why it would not work for hte function app. I have updated the snapshots in my question with this information in case I've missed something in your post. The query captures everything SELECT *
INTO myBlobOutput
FROM MyIoTHubInput

Comment: I suspect the issue might be with the access level specified at your function which is AuthorizationLevel.Function. The [Authorization document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#http-auth) says we need to pass API access key in the request when we use this setting. I do not see a way to pass this key when we bind Azure stream analytics to Azure function. Can you modify your function Authorization level to anonymous and see if that helps with the data flow

Comment: Hi @LeeLaRajesh_Sayana I think access to the api key is provided when creating the output for the Stream Analytics Job, if you see the snapshot of its creation above. I tried with both App and Function App default key to no avail. I also tried Anonymous (good thinking, thank you) but still doesn't work. Also tried creating a new brand function app and still does not work. I am wondering if this features works at all in Azure, no one at MSFT seems to respond the ask for help :(

Comment: the reason was silly, the query I had was to output to the blob. in raising the query consideration you were actually right and I didn't realize that would of course only output to the blob :)